# Deeplinking in Android app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to enable deeplinking in my app. Here is the code I am running in AndroidManifest to achieve it:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.WalletActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_wallet">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/title_activity_link_wallet" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="myapp"
            android:host="wallet" 
        />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is there anything else I need to do in order to make tapping on `myapp://wallet` to open `WalletActivity` of my app?

Comment: Have you tested it? Are you not getting the activity launched?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it by typing `myapp://wallet` on the browser, but the desired app is not opening, let alone the activity.

Comment: Try using the method suggested in the docs: adb shell am start
        -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android

Comment: that works. But shouldn't typing it in the browser work as well?

Comment: don't think so - not just entering it like that.

Comment: this might be useful: https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/

Comment: thanks a lot, guys. Can you please also tell me how do I pass extra values to the intents? I mean, suppose the activity I'm trying to open requires an extra information in order to open/work. `String abc = intent.getExtras().getString("abc");` How do I pass this value via deeplinking, or any other way?

Comment: I mean, how do I implement the functionality `intent.put(...)` in case of opening the intended activity via deeplinks? Is there something like `?a=something, b=somethingelse`, or something of that sort? If not, how do I do that?

Comment: I've replied to both of your questions in the answer section - good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app, this works fine:

```
    <activity
       android:name=".ui.WalletActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_wallet">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="wallet" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I also have extra parameters (myapp://wallet?id=42), which I parse like this:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String providerUrl = intent.getData().toString();
    UrlQuerySanitizer sanitizer = new UrlQuerySanitizer();
    sanitizer.setAllowUnregisteredParamaters(true);
    sanitizer.parseUrl(providerUrl);
    String id = sanitizer.getValue("id");
```

(You can read about `UrlQuerySanitizer` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/UrlQuerySanitizer.html))

To test, I'd suggest to send the myapp://wallet link to yourself via email, for example :-) (or adb, as mentioned in the comments)

Comment: i tried this code but getting 'null' in this line " String providerUrl = intent.getData().toString();"

Answer (score 0):

To test and make sure that your intent is working, you can use `adb` command as suggested in the [deep linking docs](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

To pass parameters in your uri, simply add them as a normal query parameter (i.e. `example://gizmos/path?key=value`, then retrieve them by parsing the intent data like this:

```
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    String value = uri.getQueryParameter("key");
```

Make sure you check for nulls etc.